# How do I combine schema markup with image alt tag?

Tags: schema, semantic-markup

I am trying to implement JSON-LD schema markup for images on my site however I do not see how schema works in addition to image alt tags. I know these are separate things but what if I want to have both? For example:

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
      {
      "@context": "http://schema.org/",
      "@type": "Organization",
      "url": "http://www.example.com/",
      "logo": "http://www.example.com/mcdonals-logo.png"
      }
    </script>

<img src="http://www.example.com/mcdonals-logo.png" alt="McDonald's Logo" />
```

Answer (score 1):

`alt` attributes are for the user and their browser. Schema markup is for search engines and bots. You don't necessarily need or want the same info in the alt tag as you do in the schema.

[HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#attr-img-alt)

> the value of the alt attribute provides equivalent content for those
>   who cannot process images or who have image loading disabled

[From the W3C](https://www.w3.org/2013/dwbp/wiki/RDF_AND_JSON-LD_UseCases#JSON-LD)

> JSON-LD was created for Web Developers who are working with data that
>   is important to other people and must interoperate across the Web. As
>   per one of lead editor of the draft The desire for better Web APIs is
>   what motivated the creation of JSON-LD, not the Semantic Web.

Comment: So then my example would make sense in providing both on the page so bots can parse schema and users can use the alt text. Is there anything wrong with my code example or a better way to provide both?

Comment: @DavidGarcia Yes, it seems to work for me but I would provide better (or no) information for your alt tag cause what you have there now is rather pointless to one who might come to it.

Comment: @Rob That `alt` attribute is perfect as is and shouldn't be removed.

Comment: @Sean I didn't say he should remove it. I said he needed to provide better information or to just leave it blank. The alt attribute is to provide the information the image was used for when it cannot be displayed. It is not to be used to merely state that it is an image of something.

Comment: @Rob The `alt` attribute is for more than just if the image doesn't load. It's a major part of accessibility. A blank `alt` isn't appropriate in this case, and "McDonald's logo" can't be improved upon.

Comment: @Sean Your first sentence is exactly what I'm talking about. Your second sentence is not appropriate. Stating a missing image is a logo means nothing to a blind person if all that does is state it's a logo. If the missing image shows a graph, and that graph can be stated in words, then that would be appropriate alt text.